# Asynchronous Module Definition: difference between beta.verb() and require("beta").verb()

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd

I was studying Asynchronous Module Definition from [wiki.commonjs.org](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/AsynchronousDefinition)
and I am wondering what is the meaning of this piece of code.
In particular, my question is:
`return beta.verb();` and `return require("beta").verb();` have the same effect.
If not what is the difference?

```
define("alpha", ["require", "exports", "beta"], function (require, exports, beta) {
    exports.verb = function() {
        return beta.verb();
        //Or:
        return require("beta").verb();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beta` is already initialized to the value of `require("beta")` before the callback function is called. From the definition of `define` on that page:

> The dependencies [argument] must be resolved *prior to execution of the module factory function*, and the resolved values should be passed as arguments to the factory function with argument positions corresponding to index in the dependencies array

Comment: So it means that if I am using `return require("beta").verb();` I do not need to pass it by argument. Am I right?

Comment: @LorraineBernard: Yes, but you'd do better to use the argument `beta`, and not include `require` in your dependencies.